# Cannot convert null to type parameter because it could be a non nullable type when expecting "T?"

Tags: c#

this code complains

```
public static T? Foo<T>()
{
   return null;
}
```

with

> Error CS0403
> Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.

But aren't I telling the compiler it can be null?

If `T` is `int`, then I want the answer to be null, not 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `T` is unconstrained in your case, and for unconstrained (neither to `struct` nor to `class`) generic type parameters `T` - `T?` is handled differently for value types and reference types. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics):

> - If the type argument for `T` is a reference type, `T?` references the corresponding nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string`, then `T?` is a `string?`.
> - **If the type argument for `T` is a value type, `T?` references the same value type, `T`. For example, if `T` is an `int`, the `T?` is also an `int`.**
> - If the type argument for `T` is a nullable reference type, `T?` references that same nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string?`, then `T?` is also a `string?`.
> - **If the type argument for `T` is a nullable value type, `T?` references that same nullable value type. For example, if `T` is a `int?`, then `T?` is also a `int?`.**

So for `Foo<int>` actual signature will be `int Foo<int>`, hence the error.

If it is suitable for you - constrain `T` to be either `struct` or `class`.

Comment: ah ok....bit odd...I think for the moment I'll constrain it to be a class.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd Yep. It is a bit odd and mainly due to the fact that nullablle reference types perform some kind of type erasure, i.e. compared to nullable value types which are actually `Nullable<T>` they are not represented with different type.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd also check [this sharplab snipped](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFCwAQFkCeAVApgZwBcA5AVwBtzkBvZVe1ABwCcBLANwENDdVsBpXJgD8fAoQDCAewB2RZp1YzC+ADwChAPgAUGzKgDWQgDR9BI1DIrlOAI3K5zqALyXrASjoNvAdwAWuMy8eqggqPKkAMaELpqGQgDcXvTJTGxcPGZConhE0nKECkoq6uY6IUaYpnqiVpR2Dk6udeSeSN6+AUFZ+mFoznGVSe0MqSwc3LxQACxiROi4hH5SwNpt3rQjHahczKiswC6oAKzD2/S7qDGuuZKy8orK+NoH7mfnAPQfqD6slJZSGKRKQAW0Yf1wqW8Xx2nD2hDgR1u+QexWeL2Uwncr3e20u+CR4hRhUeKm0ACJyW9UgBfZA0oA=) it can be a nice workaround in some cases.